# Json request working on safari but not chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

http://www.imobilus.co.uk/json%20request/index.html - live version

https://jsfiddle.net/5p6h3rtt/

Cannot work this out at all, fairly new to jquery

Works perfect on safari but is blank on chrome and firefox

```
$( document ) .ready(function() {

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=imobilus%20jobs', 
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(' b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7' + ":" + '' ));
},
    data: { username: 'b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7', password:'' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.results);

        if(data.results.length > 0) {
            var numberOfResults = data.results.length;
            $('.container').append('<div>Found '+numberOfResults+' results</div>');
            $.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
                if(index < 100) {
                    $('.container').append('<div class="my-class">'+element.locationName+'<div><div>'+element.jobDescription+'</div>');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.container').append('<div class="my-class">Sorry nothing found</div>');
        }


    }
});

});
```

EDIT:

Been messing with this for ages now and have almost got there now it works fine on Chrome and Firefox but on IE/Edge it won't show up at all and on Safari the browser asks for authentication.

```
$( document ) .ready(function() {
$.ajax({

dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7:@www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=imobilus%20jobs',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + btoa( 'b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7' + ":" + '' ));
},
data: { username: 'b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7', password:'' },
success: function (data) {
console.log(data.results);      

        if(data.results.length > 0) {
            var numberOfResults = data.results.length;
            $('.reed').append('<div>Found '+numberOfResults+' results</div>');
            $.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
                if(index < 100) {
                    $('.reed').append('<div class="my-class">'+element.locationName+'<div><div class="my-class2">'+element.jobDescription+'</div>');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.reed').append('<div class="my-class">Sorry nothing found</div>');
        }


    }
});

});
```

Comment: JSONP won't work. You can't set custom request headers using it (even if you could, blindly recommending JSONP without checking the server supports it isn't very helpful). The server must grant permission with CORS.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does the console show any errors? Does the net tab show the request being made? Does it show the response coming back? Are they both formatted as you expect with the data you expect?

Comment: Chrome comes up with this console error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=imobilus%20jobs&username=b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7&password=. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your code using `dataType: 'jsonp'` and it works fine in chrome as well.

I tested it in chrome and it works. However, there is a problem on firefox with authentication but I think is not related to this

```
$( document ) .ready(function() {

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=imobilus%20jobs', 
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(' b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7' + ":" + '' ));
},
    data: { username: 'b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7', password:'' },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.results);

        if(data.results.length > 0) {
            var numberOfResults = data.results.length;
            $('.container').append('<div>Found '+numberOfResults+' results</div>');
            $.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
                if(index < 100) {
                    $('.container').append('<div class="my-class">'+element.locationName+'<div><div>'+element.jobDescription+'</div>');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.container').append('<div class="my-class">Sorry nothing found</div>');
        }


    }
});

});
```